# How can I get the most accurate time for a process in in C?

Tags: c, time.h

I am not looking for nanoseconds or accuracy to the umpteenth decimal, however I would like to have some decent accuracy and to minimise margin of error with the results.

For this, I used sys/time.h, time.h, on a Mac Book Pro and a stop watch (my iPhone's stopwatch app, that is), and I am getting rather inconstant results.

My iPhone's stopwatch report: 140.66 seconds and the two functions with three trials are seen below:

```
1. time.h gave me 136.957065 seconds —— sys/time.h gave me 140.335872 seconds
2. time.h gave me 140.822794 seconds —— sys/time.h gave me 151.858111 seconds
3. time.h gave me 146.064458 seconds —— sys/time.h gave me 162.149713 seconds
```

And here is my code snippet:

```c
void myExpensiveFunction()
{
   struct timeval tv1, tv2;
   gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
   clock_t fbegin = clock();
        
   /* expensive algorithm */
        
   clock_t fend = clock();
   gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);

   printf("Expensive function took: %f seconds\n", (double)(fend - fbegin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
   printf("Expensive function took: %f seconds\n",
     (double)(tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 +
     (double)(tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec));
}
```

While this isn't mission critical and I am sure there are some inconsistencies due to my computer itself, I am curious if there is a better function or methodology I should be using or be aware of.  For testing and curiosity sake, I tried this same thing on my Linux mail server, and got similar results, `sys/time.h` was ten seconds slower.

Comment: You cannot get that kind of accuracy on some consumer fluff OS. Even if the OS somehow turned hard real-time through magic, the oscillator accuracy of the system clock is probably not even that good to begin with. You need a real-time system for this and not some consumer electronics.

Comment: They just don't measure the same thing.  gettimeofday() measures wall clock time.  clock() measures processor time, the actual time spent executing code.  The lower number, unless the program uses threads.  Big differences between repeated measurements is generally explained by the processor throttling down due to chip temperature and battery state.

Comment: If you get this variation in trials, then the code *doesn't* always take the same time to execute. The best you will get is an estimation, and that is usually good enough to determine where bottlenecks are.

Comment: @HansPassant - thank you!  this is what i was looking for, wall clock data is better for consumer, e.g, the compression of foo.tar.bz2 took 30 seconds.  The other is better for me to benchmark different algorithms?